# uwsgi memory consumption increases gradually but the consumed memroy not freed

Tags: python, django, nginx, uwsgi

I am running a project with django + nginx + uwsgi and my uwsgi.ini file confiuration is as follows:

```
socket = /tmp/uwsgi.sock
chmod-socket = 666
socket-timeout = 60
enable-threads  = true
threads = 500
disable-logging=True
```

with the above configuration also added harakiri = 60 but unable to free memory
then tried addition of max-request = 100 and max-worker-lifetime = 30 but memory was not freed
after this tried configuring process=4 and threads =2 but also unable to free memory usage.
while analysing my api calls I found three bulk api which increased memroy usage continuously and optimized the code. Eventhough after code optimizing and adding some parameters to uwsgi.ini file unabke to free memory. Please help me out to fix this issue.

Comment: Can you see which processes actually taking up more memory? Make sure you don't have anything inside your Django app that is not releasing memory once done (or if being terminated the way it should).

Comment: I am not sure about which processes takes up memory.

Comment: Please give a answer to the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've faced a similar issue when working with Django + Uwsgi application, this is my uwsgi.ini coniguration :

```
[uwsgi]

enable-threads  = true
threads = 100
harakiri = 30
max-request = 50
```

- Multiple threads are used to increase concurrency (I've used threads
  because they are cheaper than running multiple processes ).
- **Harakiri** -  If a request takes longer than the time specified (in seconds) the request will be droped and that worker is recycled.
- **max-request** - This is the important parameter and will limit the requests handled by process

After doing these figure out which request causes huge data query results from database and if possible optimize them.

Let me know if this works :), also a little more information would help figure out  better solution.